# Javascript functions not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, triggers

For some reason javascript functions are not working right now.

```
function alert(){
alert('Close')
}
```

When I trigger the alert using:

```
<span onclick="alert()">Hi</span>
```

I get the following error:

***Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded***

What could be wrong? Is it something wrong with jQuery?

Example (of the error): http://jsfiddle.net/qNjjN/show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that there is a native javascript function called `alert` and you are essentially overriding it with your `alert` function.

When you call your function, your function calls itself over and over.  This is called recursion and in your case results in your error.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You've overridden the default `alert()` function with your own! So when you call `alert()` within the method it is making an infinite recursive call.

Rename your method to something else and it will be fine :)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop by calling alert from itself.  This would be fine as a recursive function but there's currently no logic to end itself.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks!